# How can I get part of an input in python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm working on a little project in python. I'm creating a bot that can do several of things like flip a coin, search things on google, it's an ask eight ball. I'm working on the calculator bit. I have this so far for the calc part.

```
def calc():
pompt = "Enter problem: "
print "I can only do basic math, no alegbra"
userInput = raw_input(prompt)
if userInput.strip() != 'exit':
    calc()
```

I want to be able to determine the operator type. So if userInput is 4-3, I want to be able to read the '-' and know it's a subtraction problem. If userInput is 4+3 I want to be able to read the + and know its an addition problem.

How can I do this? I have a feeling I would need to loop, but I'm not particularly sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about the rest of the bot, but for the calculator bit you might consider tokenizing the input (there's a term you can research) and processing it as a stack. For that, look up [Reverse Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

Answer (score 2):

you can use a simple regex to split the pieces, assuming that the input is correct.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'(\d+)([\-+*\\])(\d+)')
>>> pat.search('13+5').groups()
('13', '+', '5')
```

you can then access the operator by `.groups()[1]` and check each case. Added bonus, with this regex, you can then access each operand as well.

Or, as Two_bitAlchemist suggested, you can process as a stack but that went over my head.

EDIT:

make sure to save the groups:

```
>>> l = pat.search('15-1').groups()
>>> l
('15', '-', '1')
>>> l[1]
'-'
```

Comment: you should save the list, check the edit. `pat.groups()` is invalid since pat is just the regex.

Comment: I've tried to print pat.groups()[1) but then I just get TypeError: 'int' object is not callable EDIT: Saving groups

Comment: `pat.groups` is the number of groups in your pattern. you have to call groups on your match object if you want the actual match groups, ie `pat.search(str).groups()`

Comment: There's an example of [a Reverse Polish calculator in Python on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79795/38663). The Wikipedia article I linked above has a [description of the algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) and a step-by-step example. I can expand on stacks or Reverse Polish Notation or whatever else, maybe even try to make my own example here, if there is interest. Another key point: a "stack" is an abstraction. You can make a list into a stack in a way if you're just careful how you treat it. (The example on CR does this.)